# Cascading filters in PPS, possible bug

Tags: ssas, mdx

Scenario is: **Time** controls available **Locations** and **Location** controls **Sub-Locations** so:

I have **Time dimension filter** which is cascaded to **Location filter**

and this is cascaded to **Sub-Location filter**.

Now the Time -> Location works,

but Location -> Sub-Location doesnt filter, instead shows all Sub-Locations.

I have even made connection formula in the Location -> Sub-Location connection:

```
MDX:

nonempty( <<UniqueName>> * Sub-Location.children )
```

Is it possible to cascade also the Time to the Sub-Location filter?